# Search database for value and get info c# Forms

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms, phpmyadmin

I have a database called "users" where user information is saved. When you login with your name and pass, your name is send to the homeform, where i want to get the "to-do list" that's saved in the database with your info. Here's my code so far:

```
db_connection();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username`=@username AND `todo`=@todo";
```

So basically i need to get the todo of the user (which is sent to this form as _name) lets say admin, and display it in tbTodo.

Comment: Is Todo is a field in the table user or is it another table? Your question is rather unclear. If it is another table, you cannot use the query that way

Comment: @Chit  Khine Sorry for the unclear question. Yes, it is in the same table. |ID|>|username| >|password|>|todo|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is in the same form you can try using

```
select `user`.todo from `user` where `username` = @username
```

considering username is unique

Answer (score -1):

If the main problem is parameters - u can use property Parameters: 

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user);`

There is an example in msdn:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;
        // Use AddWithValue to assign Demographics.
        // SQL Server will implicitly convert strings into XML.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demographics", demoXml);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Nice try for an answer, but the question is rather unclear at the moment, so we don't really know what OP needs.